# LinearLayout horizontal center with automatic margin/resizing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, bottomnavigationview

[image]

I'm trying to make a bottom navigation, but I cannot get rid of the centering without margin. Items should be centered and have space between them (the have a maximum width of 168dp and a minimum of 80dp [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#)). Therefore there needs to be space between them. Is there any solution with the horizontal linear layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>

// ------------------------------------
// the layout of the item (another file)
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxWidth="168dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:contentDescription="Icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hd" />

    <me.konrad.rocket.ui.components.SimpleTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `layout_weight="1"` for each item .

Comment: @ADM it still stays the same after adding it to the item layout

Comment: Do you need to use `LinearLayout`? A different layout type would accomplish this, like `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you doing it your way then you can use the method below. Have your item layout as below .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
```

And add the view at runtime as .

```
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        View mView=LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.temp2,null);
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.header)).addView(mView);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams()).weight = 1;
    }
```

This seems to solution to your problem . But other than that you should use [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) to get more of Material design . and its easy to use too.

Comment: That's the right approach, thank you. The reason I don't use BottomNavigationView is that I want to learn it on my own and there are only limited possibilities with that library. It doesn't support a height of 48dp.